# Apache, Tomcat : Load balancing not working with 2nd server

Tags: linux, debian, networking, apache-httpd, tomcat

I am working on load balancing 2 servers which have different domain names. Currently, it's working good for Server1, where load-balancing configuration and 1 instance of Tomcat is present, but not for server2. I am getting an AJP failure. I even tried with HTTPS, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Error log :

```
(110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to SERVER_2_IP:8445 (SERVER_2_IP) failed
[Tue Feb 26 09:53:40.020390 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 16991:tid 140154131154688] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (SERVER_2_IP) for 60s
[Tue Feb 26 09:53:40.020400 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 16991:tid 140154131154688] [client CLIENT_IP:40082] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: SERVER_2_IP
```

Server1 : sites-enabled/000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName DOmain.de
ServerAlias www.domain.de
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/chain.pem
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
       BalancerMember ajp://IP:8009 route=server1
       BalancerMember https://IP2:8445 route=server2
</Proxy>
 ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
 ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
</VirtualHost>
```

Server 2 tomcat :

```
<Connector port="8445" enableLookups="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
maxThreads="200" disableUploadTimeout="true" connectionTimeout="36000"
compression="off" sslProtocols="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TL$
ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
 compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/Domain2.de/keystore.jks" keyPass="PASSWORD" keyAlias="tomcat" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"/>


    <Connector port="8012" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8445" connectionTimeout="10000" keepAliveTimeout="10000" />
```

I have also given :

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8445 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8012 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save.
```

Still no luck, server 2 doesn't respond.

Comment: is mod_proxy_ajp installed? I would advise posting errors verbatim instead of mentioning them.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : My bad, I forgot to add error log. I have added error log at top of main post. For mod_proxy_ajp I am getting : a2enmod mod_proxy_ajp 
ERROR: Module mod_proxy_ajp does not exist!. However, it works for server1...

Comment: Something seems off there. Supposing 8445 is the right port, is it listening in any interface besides localhost?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : How can I know that? I have opened that port with the iptables command I mentioned.

Comment: @Freddy :  I have another balancer which is for port-80. It's like BalancerMember http://Server2_ip:8086 route=server2, but still no response. Module proxy already enabled, Module proxy_http already enabled. Thank you.

Comment: @Freddy : no, I am getting unable to connect to host. How can I open up the ports so they are accessible from outside. Iptables command I posted above should do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Freddy : Port-8445 is not reachable via lynx on server2's localhost, but http is. I am able to access the website via http on lynx on server2's localhost, but not with https. I get for https, Alert!: Unexpected network read error; connection aborted.
.

Comment: @Freddy : But as I checked, lynx faces error with https on many sites. http works fine locally.

Comment: @Freddy : Completely removed https component, working on server2, but not from outside, not from my machine locally, or from server1.

Comment: I'm not a firewall guy, but you may need an outgoing rule like `iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -p tcp --sport 80  -j ACCEPT` and for the input rule add ESTABLISHED to the state like `iptables -A INPUT  -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`. Hope that works.